# How to use purrr::pmap to invoke a user-defined function in R

Tags: r, list, user-defined-functions, purrr

I want to invoke the function `wrap_vr` using `map` or `pmap` of the `purrr` library.

First, I don't understand why I have to use `df$v1` and `df$v2` to pass the variables to the function. Why not `v1` and `v2` only?

Second, what is my error when I tried to use `pmap`?

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(cy = c('a', 'a', 'b', 'b'),
             date = c(1,2,1,2),
             v1 = c(1,2,3,1),
             v2 = c(5,3,2,1))

wrap_vr <- function(df, vr, tit, ylab){
  ggplot(data = df, aes(date, all_of(vr))) +
    geom_line(color = "steelblue", size = 1) +
    labs(title =  tit,
         y = ylab, x = "") +
    facet_wrap(~ cy)
}

wrap_vr(df, df$v1, "title_1", "ylabel_1")


wrap_vr(df, df$v2, "title_2", "ylabel_2")


list_1 <- list(df, list(df$v1, df$v2), list("title_1", "title_2"), list("ylabel_1", "ylabel_2"))

# This gives an error
pmap(list_1, ~wrap_vr(.x))
#> Error: Element 2 of `.l` must have length 1 or 4, not 2
Created on 2021-07-06 by the reprex package (v2.0.0)
```

Comment: I believe the issue with **purrr** is that your dataset is read as a list. Try `list(list(df), ...` instead of `list(df, ...`.  For passing variables into a ggplot2-based function you may be in a spot where it'd be useful to read about programming with tidyverse/ggplot2 and tidy evaluation. I most often am using strings when passing variables into ggplot2-based functions and so use the `.data` pronoun. Like `aes(x = data, y = .data[[vr]])` and then pass strings `wrap_var(df, "v1", "t1", "y1")`.

Comment: Thanks. Using the `.data` pronoun resulted, but the transformation of `df` into `list(df)` didn't.

Comment: @sbac, your df is a constant for all iterations, so it should be passed outside the list.

Comment: @sbac Yep, I missed a step. Then do `pmap(list_1, wrap_vr)` to pass things from the list in order to the function (no `.x`). I agree with others that if df is going to be fixed you may be able to make it part of your function.

Comment: Rory has showed it correctly.  However, it is also advised that other column names may not be used as constant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing a couple of things in your code fixes this problem. First, your dataset shouldn't be read as a list, so you can take that out of `list_1`.

```
list_1 <- list(list(df$v1, df$v2), list("title_1", "title_2"), list("ylabel_1", "ylabel_2"))
```

From there, you can phrase your pmap call like this to get the results you're after:

```
pmap(list_1, ~wrap_vr(df, ..1, ..2, ..3))
```

Answer (score 2):

Apart from the two problems listed there is one more problem, you are passing date and cy columns as constant assuming that it will always be there.
Nevertheless, my suggestion is to use these columns as default names.

so

- your first problem can be tackled using `.data[[vars]]`
- your second problem can be tackled by removing df from the list
- additionally, your custom_function is suggested to be modified further by using two more argument albeit with default values.
- Also suggested to use df argument in last with a default value
- Thus, in your function you'll have to pass it three arguments, others will use default values.

Demo

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(cy = c('a', 'a', 'b', 'b'),
             date = c(1,2,1,2),
             v1 = c(1,2,3,1),
             v2 = c(5,3,2,1))

wrap_vr <- function( vr, tit, ylab, c1 = 'date', c2 = 'cy', df = df){
  df %>% ggplot(aes(.data[[c1]], .data[[vr]])) +
    geom_line(color = "steelblue", size = 1) +
    labs(title =  tit,
         y = ylab, x = "") +
    facet_wrap(~ .data[[c2]])
}

wrap_vr( 'v1', "title_1", "ylabel_1")
```

[image]

```r
wrap_vr( 'v2', "title_2", "ylabel_2")
```

[image]

```r
list_1 <- list(list('v1', 'v2'), list("title_1", "title_2"), list("ylabel_1", "ylabel_2"))

pmap(list_1, ~wrap_vr(..1, ..2, ..3))
#> [[1]]
```

[image]

```
#> 
#> [[2]]
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-07-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

The use of `pmap` in this case will result in empty lists printing in the console (or inside a markdown). Because `wrap_vr()` is called by it's side effects (show a graphic) and doesn't return anything, it's better to use `pwalk()` function like this:

Regarding to writing `v1` instead of `df$v1` we'll need to modify a `wrap_vr()` to contemplate the fact that `v1` need to be stored inside a list as an expression (to avoid 'object v1 not found` error).

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rlang)

df <- tibble(cy = c('a', 'a', 'b', 'b'),
             date = c(1,2,1,2),
             v1 = c(1,2,3,1),
             v2 = c(5,3,2,1))

wrap_vr <- function(df, vr, tit, ylab){
  print(
  ggplot(data = df, aes(date, all_of(vr))) +
    geom_line(color = "steelblue", size = 1) +
    labs(title =  tit,
         y = ylab, x = "") +
    facet_wrap(~ cy))
}

list_1 <- list(list(df, df), list(df$v1, df$v2), list("title_1", "title_2"), list("ylabel_1", "ylabel_2"))

pwalk(list_1, wrap_vr)
```

## Option 2

```
#to avoid calling df twice inside the list
list_2 <- list(list(df$v1, df$v2), list("title_1", "title_2"), list("ylabel_1", "ylabel_2"))

pwalk(list_2, wrap_vr, df = df)
```

## option 3

```
#or quoting the column names

#because column names will go inside a list, we'll need a mechanism to avoid evaluation.

wrap_vr_expr <- function(df, vr, tit, ylab){
  print(
    ggplot(data = df, aes(date, eval_tidy(vr))) +
      geom_line(color = "steelblue", size = 1) +
      labs(title =  tit,
           y = ylab, x = "") +
      facet_wrap(~ cy))
}

list_3 <- list(list(df, df), list(expr(v1), expr(v2)), list("title_1", "title_2"), list("ylabel_1", "ylabel_2"))

pwalk(list_3, wrap_vr_expr)
```